# Unable to stop daemons? 100+ busy daemons could not be reused?

Tags: android, react-native, gradlew

React native project where I'm trying to build the android version with ./gradlew assembleRelease. Results in "Starting daemon, X busy and X stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details."

./gradlew --stop does not work, results in "Could not stop daemon. Daemon may have crashed."

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.